# error: request for member 'size' in '', which is of non-class type 'int*'

Tags: c++, class

I dont know why I have this problem right now!

> error: request for member 'size' in 'isbn', which is of non-class type 'int*'

I am trying to get how many elements (integers) are in `isbn`.

```cpp
class Book{
protected:
    int isbn[20];
    char title[50];
    char author[30];
    float basic_price;
public:
    Book(int *isbn=0,const char *title="",const char *author="",float basic_price=0)
    {
 //Problem is in this line:
       for(int i=0;i<isbn.size();i++)
            this->isbn[i]=isbn[i];
        strcpy(this->title,title);
        strcpy(this->author,author);
        this->basic_price=basic_price;
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you expect to get for `.size()` on an `int*`?

Comment: How many elements are in the isbn variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: _"I dont know why I have this problem right now!"_ it takes some practice, but what you want to do is read the error message and try to understand what it is telling you.  I am guessing that something or someone made you believe that there exists some member function named `size()` for the type you were using it on.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, arrays don't have a `size()` method.

The best thing you can do by a country mile is replace

```
int isbn[20];
```

with

```
std::vector<int> isbn;
```

And grow the vector accordingly. Use a `std::string` in place of the `char` arrays.

Comment: Using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) will be good instead of arrays of `char`.

Comment: and `std::array` for fixed size, maybe `isbn` is a good candidate, the others probably not

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `int*` doesn't have member function `size()`. You have to determine the size in another way.

The fixed value `20` (from the size of the member array `isbn`) might work, but be careful not to cause out-of-range access.

Another option is adding another argument to pass the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of elements in a C-style array, you have a couple of options. For example, for

```
int xs[5];
```

you can use either

1. `sizeof(xs)/sizeof(xs[0])`
2. `std::size(xs)`

Note, that [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is a C++17 feature.

Be aware that you need the type of the variable to be an array reference. If you only have a pointer to the first array element, this won't work. So, in the code example, this will work for `this->isbn`, whose type is `int(&)[20]`, but not for the `isbn` the function argument, whose type is `int*`.

Comment: You have to write `this->isbn`, not `isbn`, in this case. The methods won't work with pointers.

Comment: @MikeCAT I overlooked the fact that he had a function argument with the same name as a member variable. If the size of the input array is what matters here, i.e. it can be smaller than that of the member, the OP should just pass the input size as an additional argument. That's what one does in C, and if he's using C arrays, it seems like a fitting solution.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use size() with conventional array, for using size() you have to use std::vector which is a container of STL.
For initializing a vector with an array use: `vector<int> vec(isbn,isbn+20)`

Otherwise you can replace the for statement in your code with :

```
 for(int i=0; isbn[i]; i++)
```

Thanx